# Is there this use? "Us not being in the same area"

Tags: meaning

Is it possible to use this kind of construction? Starting a sentence with an object pronoun.

Comment: It is common and natural speech when it is following or followed by another statement to clarify context or intent. In informal writing, it may be acceptable.

Comment: Acceptability seems a movable feast around possible Comp-V-S sentences. 'What he struggles with is us not being in the same area.' (Fine; wh-cleft, acc in the 'It's us'-type structure,  ACC-ing) ←────?→  'Us not being in the same area is what he struggles with.' (little difference, really).

Comment: (a) _Us not being in the same area_ is not a sentence. It is a subordinate gerund clause, and can't appear as an independent simple sentence. It can, however, appear in a complex sentence, like _With us not being in the same area, it's hard to chat._ (b) Gerund clauses may have a subject in the objective or the genitive form. _Us_ is, as noted, objective. So, on the whole, yes, it is possible to use this kind of construction.

Comment: It can be the answer to a question, as-is *["What's the biggest obstacle to you pursuing the relationship right now?"]*. Also, welcome to ELL.